# How to improve resolution of image on Android

Tags: android, xml, image, android-studio, resolution

I have uploaded an image which is on 3000 by 3000 pixel onto Android Studios.

When I try to add the image to my application, the image does not look sharp.

[image]

Here is my XML code

```
 <ImageView
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="200dip"
   android:scaleType="fitCenter"
   android:contentDescription=""
   android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
   android:layout_marginBottom="28dip"
   android:src="@mipmap/login_logo" />
```

I believe that my image should be big enough for the image view. Can anyone advise me on how to increase the resolution of my image?

Updated

When I uploaded the image, the 4 different versions of the image were created automatically in the system

[image]

Comment: @Enzokie, yes the versions were already created as shown in my updated screenshot in the OP.

Comment: you can use 9 patch images .

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya, thanks. What does adjustviewbounds do?

Comment: the problem is that when android studio import your image it will resize to the recommended size for icons, look @adalPaRi's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating an icon set, wich actually does not have 3000 by 3000 pixel. Check it.

The application is using the more appropiate size (hdpi, xhdpi, etc). But you are resizing manually. That's why the icon is not sharp in the screen.

When you create a manual Image Asset, this is the real size depending on screen size. The assistan takes the original image and resizze it.

```
ldpi (low) ~120dpi
mdpi (medium) ~160dpi
hdpi (high) ~240dpi
xhdpi (extra-high) ~320dpi
xxhdpi (extra-extra-high) ~480dpi
xxxhdpi (extra-extra-extra-high) ~640dpi
```

In pixels:

```
36x36 (0.75x) for low-density
48x48 (1.0x baseline) for medium-density
72x72 (1.5x) for high-density
96x96 (2.0x) for extra-high-density
144x144 (3.0x) for extra-extra-high-density
192x192 (4.0x) for extra-extra-extra-high-density
```

You can solve it, creating your custom image asset following this instructions:

```
LDPI - 0.75x
MDPI - Original size you want to show
HDPI - 1.5x
XHDPI - 2.0x
XXHDPI - 3x
XXXHDPI - 4.0x
```

> https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Or you can use an external library, like Picasso, to load the original image and fit it. The result will be more professional as far as you can dynamically fit, use placeholders, errorimage, etc.

> https://www.google.es/?ion=1&espv=2#q=picasso%20android

```
Picasso.with(getActivity())
    .load(new File("path-to-file/file.png"))
    .into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest a method which use in onCreate() function. It used `BitmapFactory` to load your image

```
Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inScaled = false;
Bitmap source = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(a.getResources(), path, options);
ImageView mImg;
mImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
mImg.setImageBitmap(source);
```

Comment: a 3000x3000 32bits Bitmap would occupy 36MB, are you sure this is a good idea?

Comment: His question just aims to increase the resolution of the image. I just give him an option for this. If it is too large, he can use a scale to reduce the resolution. It is one parameter in the above code

Comment: android can handle different size images for different densities, why do you want to do it the dirty way?

Comment: I don't think it is a dirty way. Instead of directly load image in Android Studio folder, we can load it in the project folder to maintain the resolution. In some case, the input image is very low. My way is one option that make sense in that case

Comment: What is a.getResources() and  path here ?